# Wpf DataGrid SelectionUnit throwing Error?

Tags: c#, wpf

Error: The current value of the SelectionUnit property on the parent DataGrid prevents rows from being selected.

```
    <DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"
      SelectionUnit="Cell"
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
      CanUserResizeRows="False"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      >
```

All i want is i have a checkbox column if someone clicks on that full row is slected. I want if the user clicks other colums other parts of the row gets selected except checkbox column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding checkbox contradicts with `IsReadOnly` property. Try setting it false and then using checkbox.

Comment: I tried that i made it a templatecolumn inside that i placed checkbox then also its giving the same error.